# How to select the child elements of a particular element without having to type the name of parent again and again?

Tags: html, css

I want to do something like
CSS:

```
.parent {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: black;

  .child {
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    background-color: red;
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
  </div>
</div>
```

But this doesn't work. I will have to do this:

```
.parent {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: black;
}

.parent .child {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

I will have to type the parent name again and again if there are many children elements inside parent. Is there any short way to do it?

Comment: mate you can just make it outide parent ...like you set the parent  you set the child:   .parent {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: black;
}
.child {
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    background-color: red;
  }

Comment: Try `scss`, which supports the nesting and other multiple features

Comment: We might get this in a future version of CSS - https://drafts.csswg.org/css-nesting/

Comment: @NoobDEV-GBL I want to apply the css properties to only .child inside .parent. If I keep it outside, it will be applied to all classes with class name "child" which I don't want

Comment: @noob_coder yes i know, thats why i remove my answer

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to do with css (nesting related styles) requires a pre-processor. I would recommend reading about [Sass](https://sass-lang.com).

If you're trying to be really specific, and apply these properties only to elements inside `.parent` that have the `.child` class, you need to have the parent selector before the actual selector. ( `.parent .child { }`)

If you want to apply it to all elements that have a class `.child` you could just directly apply the style, without specifying a parent selector.

```css
.child {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: red;
}

.parent {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [SCSS](https://sass-lang.com/), you can have the multi level nesting.

On top of that feature, there are other beautiful features that's being provided by SCSS-lang. Check out the official [site](https://sass-lang.com/)